# How can I fix this "not quite synchronized" consumer producer example

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, synchronization, reentrantlock

I am trying to familiarize myself with the ReentrantLock and ConditionVariable classes. I implemented this Scala code ( without anything "Scala specific" in it ):

```
object Conditioned {

    var pops        = 0
    var max         = 20

    abstract class NamedThread extends Thread {
        def myName = this.toString
    }

    class Producer(lock:Lock,condition:Condition,source:ListBuffer[Int]) extends NamedThread {
        override def run = {
            var number   = max
            var current  = 0
            while(current < number) 
            {
                if(lock.tryLock)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        current += 1
                        source  += current
                        println("producer added data:"+current)
                        condition.signal
                    } finally { 
                        lock.unlock 
                        Thread.sleep(100)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
class Consumer(lock:Lock,condition:Condition,source:ListBuffer[Int]) extends NamedThread {
        override def run = {
            while(pops < max) {
                println("awaiting")
                while(source.isEmpty)
                    condition.await
                println("consumer try lock")
                if(lock.tryLock)
                {
                    try {
                            val data = source(source.size - 1)
                            source  -= data
                            println("consumer received data:"+data+" hello from:"+myName)
                            pops += 1
                    } finally { lock.unlock }
               } 
            }            
        }
    }

    def main(args:Array[String]) = {
        val lock        = new ReentrantLock
        val condition   = lock.newCondition
        var lb          = new collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]()
        val producer    = new Producer(lock,condition,lb)
        val consumer    = new Consumer(lock,condition,lb)
        val cons2       = new Consumer(lock,condition,lb)
        val threads     = Array(producer,consumer,cons2)
        threads.foreach(_.start)
        threads.foreach(_.join)
    }
}
```

I am trying to produce 20 elements in a ListBuffer, and then read them. I am missing something, because my output tends to look like this:

```
awaiting
consumer try lock
producer added data:1
awaiting
consumer try lock
consumer received data:1 hello from:Thread[Thread-51,5,trap.exit]
awaiting
awaiting
producer added data:2
producer added data:3
producer added data:4
producer added data:5
producer added data:6
producer added data:7
producer added data:8
producer added data:9
producer added data:10
producer added data:11
producer added data:12
producer added data:13
producer added data:14
producer added data:15
producer added data:16
producer added data:17
producer added data:18
producer added data:19
producer added data:20
```

But I don't know what. I am using a ConditionVariable so that I can signal the Consumer when data has been added, but it seems it only works the first time , and after that the producer runs until it finishes. What do I need to change to make it run in a consumer-producer fashion, and not in a robot worker kind of way? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your consumer must `await` *while holding the lock* (as the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await%28%29) for the method state).

also, you shouldn't be using `tryLock`, you should just be using `lock`.  you only use `tryLock` if you are going to do *something else* if lock acquisition fails.  in your case, if lock acquisition fails, you just try to acquire it again.

Comment: But if the consumer awaits while holding the lock, how can the producer add data? Wouldn't the producer's tryLock return false every time?

Comment: @Senthess - i added a link to the javadocs, since it is all explained there.